# Finding orthocenter of a triangle without using the altitudes.

Tags: geometry

I stumbled upon the following construction of the orthocenter for any triangle, and it does not employ the altitudes. I believe I have proved it (in 2 different ways):

1. Using the Euler line.
2. Using a proof based on a parallelogram with vetices: i) triangle vertex, ii) orthocenter iii) another triangle vertex iv) point of third triangle vertex reflected through circumcenter onto circumcircle. (Second proof is inspired by theorem 256 page 164 of Advanced Euclidean Geometry by Roger A. Johnson.)

I am sure this has been found by someone previously, but I cannot find any references to it. Perhaps it has not been found worthy of any attention.

My question then is: Has this construction/problem been discussed in the literature?

The construction is as follows:

Take any triangle with vertices A, B, C.
Make circumcircle, center O.
Reflect triangle in circumcenter O: A->A', B->B', C->C', where all primed points are on the circumcircle of triangle ABC.
Join A' with midpoint of BC and extend (line L). Do similarily for the oher primed points (i.e. join B' with midpoint of AC (line M) and C' with midpoint of AB (line N) and extend these lines).

Lines L, M and N meet at the orthocenter.

Comment: FYI: If you're allowing reflection in points, then you can simplify your construction to: *Reflect any vertex $P$ in the circumcenter to get $P'$, and reflect $P'$ in the midpoint of the side opposite $P$ to get the orthocenter.*

Comment: Yes, indeed a truly nice simplification, and its' content is the very core of my proof in 2), where the lines A'H and BC  are the diagonals of the parallelogram A'HBC (and similarily for the the two other vertices B and C with the eqivalently related points). So under my main title above, your beautiful simplification certainly is the preferred construction.

Comment: For analogy with the theorem «altitudes of a triangle are concurrent», I would perhaps prefer the construction using all three lines L, M, N.

Comment: The concurrence analogy is a good one, so I respect your preference. ... I'll note that the double-reflection invites a generalization that reflects vertex $P$ in an *arbitrary* pt $U$, then in opposite midpt $M$, to give $U'$ with $$U'=A+B+C-2U \quad\to\quad U'-\frac13(A+B+C)=-2\left(U-\frac13(A+B+C)\right)$$ Ie, $U'$ is the dilation of $U$ by factor $-2$ in the triangle's centroid. (Your construction highlights Euler's observation about the circumcenter and orthocenter.) Indeed, $P$ itself can be arbitrary, if $M$ is taken as its centroid-dilation by $-1/2$, but that may be going too far. :)

Comment: I'm not quite clear.  Is the circumcenter $O$ given (in addition to $\triangle ABC$)?  If it is not given, don't you need to know how to construct a perpendicular to get $O$?

Comment: «Blue», great insight and very interesting.

Comment: «mrtwhs», no restrictions on construction other than the usual one: «only compass and straight edge are allowed». I am just fascinated by the above fact that these three lines L, M, N (all of the «same kind») are concurrent in the orthocenter. I'd still like to know if this has been treated previously in the literature.